# Removing python pandas data parse error while reading .docx file

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, math

In the sample data frame

```
YYYYMM q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 q0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5
197501  2 11 12 26 25 10 29 21 30 22  8  7 14  4 13
197502 27 22  8 20  6 26 21  4 19  9 10  1 11 12 23
197503  8  7 21 22 25  9  4 30  2 19 10 11 28 12 27
197504 29 28 27 17 19  2 30 16 18  3  9 10 11  8 13
197505 11 15 12 31 28 24  1 30 13 18  5  6 16  7 20
197506 24 10 27  8 23 28 25 26  9 22  2 12 29 30  1
```

After reading it

```
df1=pd.read_csv("Qdays_Ddays.docx",low_memory=False) #error_bad_lines=False)
```

Getting an error

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

Please help to rectify it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53256091/how-can-i-fix-error-tokenizing-data-on-pandas-csv-reader

Comment: ```UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb5 in position 1: invalid start byte```

Comment: Microsoft Word files are not plain text files. Save your data as a plain text file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't read docx with pandas, however you can read it with [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import docx
import pandas as pd
 
# open connection to Word Document
doc = docx.Document("test.docx")
 
# read in each paragraph in file
result = [p.text for p in doc.paragraphs]
print(result)

#Then you can convert it to Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
#You can specify the return orientation.
df.to_dict('series')
#or 
df.to_dict('split')
#or
df.to_dict('records')
#or
df.to_dict('index')
```