# Dataframe saved and loaded row size different in osx

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Something very odd happened to me. I saved a dataframe file with 100,000 rows and but the loaded row size is different. The logic was tested in windows and working fine but not in osx.

I wonder if someone had same problem as me or I am missing something.

Here is the code:

```
dataframe.to_csv('./aa.csv', index=False)
print(dataframe.shape)
df = pd.read_csv('./aa.csv')
print(df.shape)
```

and the result

```
(100000, 128)
(167469, 128)
```

I tested with random dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100000, 128)))
```

Then the test result is as I expected

```
(100000, 128)
(100000, 128)
```

So I think there might be a problem with my data however I don't know where to start with. I'd like to know that if this kind of problem happens when dataframe under a certain condition.

Added:
I found one more odd.

```
print(dataframe.ORD_NO[0])
0    22424855
0    22019413
0    21988486
0    22026683
0    22385278
0    21999297
0    22006981
0    22041489
0    22529317
0    22340157
Name: ORD_NO, dtype: object

print(df.ORD_NO[0])
22424855.0
```

it seems like dataframe indexing is not working properly. I hope this detection would help to explain.

Comment: is there a merge or concat happening in your code? I think there is some duplication happening. What you can do is load both csvs and do a diff to see what's duplicated between the two dataframes.

Comment: yes. df.append(df2) is happening.

Comment: and even if I comment out the append logic for dataframe, it is still making same problem

Comment: where does df2 come from ? are you 100% sure you are working with identical data?

Comment: yes, first df is from selected data from database, and second df is also from selected data from database but df and df2 is selected with different date. I am 100% sure that they are different. But somehow the indexing or some merging logic is totally corrupted, I think.

Comment: And even if those two selected data are same, they should be considered as different dataset in dataframe view point.

Comment: then I will have to defer to the experts here as this is out of my depth! best of luck

Comment: Okay... When it is being saved, some of the items are duplicated and multiplied. I found that some unique key values are duplicated after saved. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: I found out the solution. I think there was a problem with dataframe.  I saved data with only small portion at a time, and there was a problem caused when loading at certain index. this is related to this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998740/error-in-reading-a-csv-file-in-pandascparsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-err

Comment: Ah,thanks for the update, good job on finding the solution post it as an answer and accept it so others who come across this know the issue :)

Comment: I thank you for saying that. But I don't know why this causes to load as multiple additional rows and not raise an error. This is very weird. But as the link says when I put the "lineterminator='\n'" then the dataframe loads the data with number of rows I expected.