# How to get rid of this error "b'log/.ipynb_checkpoints' does not exist " when merging two files?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to merge two files with same filenames from two different folders, as shown below.

```py
import os
import pandas as pd


files_in_log = set(os.listdir('xml'))
files_in_location = set(os.listdir('location'))
#os.mkdir('results')
for filename in files_in_log & files_in_location:
    df1 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('xml', filename))    
    df2 = pd.read_csv(os.path.join('location', filename))    
    new_df = df2.merge(df1, on=['hour'], how='outer')    
    new_df.to_csv(os.path.join('results', filename))
```

At first it was fine until I recently got error:

```
b'log/.ipynb_checkpoints' does not exist
```

I am using Python in Jupyter notebook.
How should I get rid this errors and get the program to work?

Comment: Something like [Error tokenizing data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998740/error-in-reading-a-csv-file-in-pandascparsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-err) will help you find the problem file perhaps.  Look at the accepted solution.

Comment: Thanks. Tried engine=python and it worked. So now the only problem is the second error of ipynb file I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issue with processing audio files for a dataset. Open a terminal and cd to the directory with the issue and type in the command line:

```
find . -name ".ipynb_checkpoints" -print -delete
```

This will print all .ipynb_checkpoints found in that directory and delete them.