# file written by df.to_csv cannot be read by pd.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe I read from json, process, and save to csv.
The df looks fine in terms of shape and df.head(), tail look fine.
I write to a csv then read and get an error -

```
df = get_json(params)        
df.to_csv(f'fname.csv')
testdf = pd.read_csv(f'fname.csv')

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.
```

Is there some 'careful write' I should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my experience with this issue, there was some problem with the default engine and doing this helped me:

```py
df.read_csv('input.csv', engine = 'python')
```

Comment: What will this do? *Why* should the OP do this? An answer isn't just to tell someone what to do, it should explain the reasoning so they understand the process better and don't make a similar mistake in the future.

Comment: Your edit is perfectly fine, thanks.

Comment: this worked for me , thx. From the docs, the python engine is 'slower but more complete'

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, there are some carriage returns '\r' in the data that pandas uses as a line terminator as if it was '\n'. So specifying lineterminator='\n' could resolve your issue:

```
testdf = pd.read_csv(f'fname.csv', lineterminator='\n')
```

You can also take a look at your data to see exactly where the error is occurring, please refer to this:

[Error in Reading a csv file in pandas[CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998740/error-in-reading-a-csv-file-in-pandascparsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-err)

Comment: Same comment as on the other (as of now) answer - What will this do? *Why* should the OP do this? An answer isn't just to tell someone what to do, it should explain the reasoning so they understand the process better and don't make a similar mistake in the future.

Comment: @MattDMo, thank you for pointing out - have updated my answer. Will keep this in mind for the next answers i post.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that helps, although in this case the answer came from another question, so this question is really a duplicate of the other. If you come across a situation like that, use the **flag** option under the question and give the URL of the duplicate. That way moderators or people with enough privileges (like me) can close the question as a dupe. This avoids needless repetition across the site. Thanks for participating!

Comment: this didnt make any difference for me