# `_csv.Error: line contains NUL` from a downloaded csv

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, character-encoding

I have downloaded a csv file from an url and used `csv.reader` to read its content. However I am getting `_csv.Error: line contains NUL` when I try to iterate over the `_csv.reader` object.

I have to mention that **if I manually copy paste (`ctrl+a, ctrl+c` and `ctrl+v` ) the contents of the csv manually to a different csv the code works.**

This is the code so far.

```
import csv
import requests

url='https://sedo.com/fileadmin/documents/resources/expiring_domain_auctions.csv'

response=requests.get(url)

with open('downloaded_csv.csv','wb') as out_file:
    out_file.write(response.content) # file is written properly in disk, can open with editor

with open('downloaded_csv.csv',newline='') as in_file:
    csv_contents=csv.reader(in_file,delimiter=';')
    print((csv_contents))
    for row in csv_contents: # _csv.Error: line contains NUL
        print(row)
```

Can anyone tell me how I can read the contents of this file in my python program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The file is encoded as UTF-16, so this encoding must be specified when reading the file.

```
>>> # Check the first 100 characters...
>>> r = requests.get(url)
>>> r.content.decode('utf-16')[:100]
'sep=;\n"Domain Name";"Start Time";"End Time";"Reserve Price";"Domain is IDN";"Domain has hyphen";"Dom'
```

Depending on your platform, you need to open the file like this:

```
with open('downloaded_csv.csv', newline='', encoding=encoding) as in_file:
```

where the value of encoding is one of `utf-16, utf-16-le, utf-16-be`

Note that you may need to remove or skip the initial `"sep=;"` line.

Comment: For the standard English alphabet, UTF-16 encodes to `a byte and a null byte` so if an application is complaining about null bytes in text it's usually worth checking whether the text bytes can be decoded as UTF-16.  Also Windows used to use UTF-16 for unicode enabled systems (I don't know if it still does).