# ParseError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file. (read_csv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I cannot use read_csv method of pandas properly on kaggle. Error that I get is:

ParseError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Buffer overflow caught - possible malformed input file.

I found some suggestions about this (read_excel, read by column). However, they do not help me to solve this error.

Comment: Searching on this error message gives many good options such as a way to find exactly which line in the csv is bad, switching to the python engine, or defining a different line termination character (\n instead of \r\n). see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998740/error-in-reading-a-csv-file-in-pandascparsererror-error-tokenizing-data-c-err

Comment: I am using donald_trump CSV that in the https://www.kaggle.com/manchunhui/us-election-2020-tweets notebook. Verified answer of topic that you've send me is not good solution and it does not have enough description to make sense.

Comment: I found good solutation to fix this problem. Adding engine='python' to read_csv method as a parameter.  pd.read_csv('csv_path', engine='python'). Ok - how does this solve a problem?

Comment: I don't know in this case, but CSV is generally loosely defined - some encoders may miss certain escapes that cause other parsers problems. Normally a CSV has `\r\n` line endings but if a lone `\r` is floating around in there, or there are other anomolies, some parsers will choke. Pandas normally uses a C parser that is not too forgiving. But it can also use a python one that will handle more cases. I can't say for sure what is messed up in this case.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I understood the case. I did not know what pandas uses C engine to read csv. Otherwise, Using python engine enables us to scan and read csv(maybe excel) more flexible.

Comment: Yes, but there is a trade-off, depending on the data. It looks like you are reading in text which pandas keeps as python string objects. If its a native pandas type, it will read the csv faster and compactly using the C engine. So its data source dependent. General rule, don't use the python parser unless the C parser fails.

Comment: Exactly, slowness problem of reading CSV with python can be seen clearly. For this, it should not be first choice. When I try adding lineterminator='\n' to read_csv method as parameter, it also solved my problem. It is faster way than using python as engine while reading csv.

Comment: That's interesting. I don't know if that would end up with extraneous "\r" at the end of the last column for each row. It could be that the CSV was only `\n` terminated. `\r\n` termination is very common in older text based protocols, even http.

Comment: Yes that is interesting but thanks to this, I learnt many details about reading CSV with various ways and its methodology. We need to add many condition to read csv that uploaded from client read fast and without problems on the back-end.
Read normally. If there is an error,
Read with different ways. (like including in the end of row only \n)
The last choice should be using python engine while reading CSV.

Comment: If you plan to use the CSV multiple times, you could have a separate cleaner script that fixes it and either saves it "clean" or writes with a higher performance format. You have arrow, feather, parquet, hdf table available.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the same problem just by adding `engine='python'`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(fname, sep='\t',
                 engine='python',
                 header=None)
```